# how to get the string value and save it in database

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using spring form tags and hibernate..

my jsp page has the follwoing code:

```
<tr><td><form:input path="userEnteredHostNameString" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
<td><form:input path="userEnteredDirectoryString" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
<td><form:input path="userEnteredUserNameString" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
<td><form:input path="userEnteredPasswordString" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td></tr>
```

getters and setters in my location.java

```
public String getUserEnteredHostNameString() {
        return userEnteredHostNameString;
    }
    public void setUserEnteredHostNameString(String userEnteredHostNameString) {
        if (userEnteredHostNameString!=null) userEnteredHostNameString = userEnteredHostNameString.toUpperCase();
        this.userEnteredHostNameString = userEnteredHostNameString;
    }
    public String getUserEnteredDirectoryString() {
        return userEnteredDirectoryString;
    }
    public void setUserEnteredDirectoryString(String userEnteredDirectoryString) {
        if (userEnteredDirectoryString!=null) userEnteredDirectoryString = userEnteredDirectoryString.toUpperCase();
        this.userEnteredDirectoryString = userEnteredDirectoryString;
    }
    public String getUserEnteredUserNameString() {
        return userEnteredUserNameString;
    }
    public void setUserEnteredUserNameString(String userEnteredUserNameString) {
        if (userEnteredUserNameString!=null) userEnteredUserNameString = userEnteredUserNameString.toUpperCase();
        this.userEnteredUserNameString = userEnteredUserNameString;
    }
    public String getUserEnteredPasswordString() {
        return userEnteredPasswordString;
    }
    public void setUserEnteredPasswordString(String userEnteredPasswordString) {
        if (userEnteredPasswordString!=null) userEnteredPasswordString = userEnteredPasswordString.toUpperCase();
        this.userEnteredPasswordString = userEnteredPasswordString;
    }
```

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
FtpScanEvents f = new FtpScanEvents();
        if(location.getUserEnteredHostNameString()!=null){
            f.setHostName(location.getUserEnteredHostNameString());
            }
        if(location.getUserEnteredDirectoryString()!=null){
            f.setDirectory(location.getUserEnteredDirectoryString());
            }
        if(location.getUserEnteredUserNameString()!=null){
            f.setUserName(location.getUserEnteredUserNameString());
            }
        if(location.getUserEnteredPasswordString()!=null){
            f.setPassword(location.getUserEnteredPasswordString());
            }
        ftpDao.save(f);
```

FtpScanEvents table has `hostName, directory, username, password, locationId, idx, Id` as columns..

hbm mapping file for ftpscanevents:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="ca.ups.tundra.model">
    <class name="FtpScanEvents" table="FTP_SCAN_EVENTS">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="hostName" type="string" column="HOSTNAME" length="200"/>
        <property name="directory" type="string" column="DIRECTORY" length="200"/>
        <property name="userName" type="string" column="USERNAME" length="20"/>
        <property name="password" type="string" column="PASSWORD" length="20"/>
        <many-to-one name="location" class="Location" cascade="all">
            <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

save(e entity) code..

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void save(E entity) {
        if(entity == null)
            throw new NullArgumentException("entity");
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        s.saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
```

when it comes to `ftpDao.save(f);` program terminates and there are no errors in the console..any suggestion is greatly appreciated..

Comment: where is ur FtpDao.save code ?

Comment: added the code for save method..

Comment: add print in the save or debug step by step

Comment: got solved. i was missing a property in the mapping file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the save method, I was missing a property. Added that property with a if condition and it worked!